# Reading csv files from microsoft Azure using R

Tags: r, azure, databricks

I have recently started working with databricks and azure.

I have microsoft azure storage explorer. I ran a jar program on databricks 
which outputs many csv files in the azure storgae explorer in the path

```
..../myfolder/subfolder/output/old/p/
```

The usual thing I do is to go the folder `p` and download all the csv files
by right clicking the `p` folder and click `download` on my local drive
and these csv files in R to do any analysis.

My issue is that sometimes my runs could generate more than 10000 csv files 
whose downloading to the local drive takes lot of time.

I wondered if there is a tutorial/R package which helps me to read in
the csv files from the path above without downloading them. For e.g.
is there any way I can set

```
..../myfolder/subfolder/output/old/p/
```

as my working directory and process all the files in the same way I do.

EDIT: 
the full url to the path looks something like this:

```
https://temp.blob.core.windows.net/myfolder/subfolder/output/old/p/
```

Comment: Are your files in HDFS, or in local storage on the edge node?

Comment: The files are in csv. I am not sure what you mean by local storage on the edge node? I am new to this so not much familiar with the jargon. I could give you more details if you need it.

Comment: I mean, where is your jar program creating its output files? Is it dumping them directly into a storage account?

Comment: ie, you run your jar program and then your files are available at `https://temp.blob.core.windows.net/<path-to-files>`?

Comment: Yes. It is dumping them directly to the storage account. The path I posted above is the path where the jar file is dumping the results which are in csv format.

Comment: Yes. Correct `https://temp.blob.core.windows.net/<path-to-files>` this is the path where the csv files are avilable,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the offical document [`CSV Files`](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/read-csv.html) of Azure Databricks, you can directly read a csv file in R of a notebook of Azure Databricks as the R example of the section [`Read CSV files notebook example`](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/read-csv.html#read-csv-files) said, as the figure below.

[image]

Alternatively, I used R package `reticulate` and Python package `azure-storage-blob` to directly read a csv file from a blob url with sas token of Azure Blob Storage.

Here is my steps as below.

1. I created a R notebook in Azure Databricks workspace.
2. To install R package `reticulate` via code `install.packages("reticulate")`.

   [image]
3. To install Python package `azure-storage-blob` as the code below.

   ```
   %sh
   pip install azure-storage-blob
   ```

   [image]
4. To run Python script to generate a sas token of container level and to use it to get a list of blob urls with sas token, please see the code below.

   ```
   library(reticulate)
   py_run_string("
   from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService
   from azure.storage.blob import BlobPermissions
   from datetime import datetime, timedelta

   account_name = '<your storage account name>'
   account_key = '<your storage account key>'
   container_name = '<your container name>'

   blob_service = BaseBlobService(
       account_name=account_name,
       account_key=account_key
   )

   sas_token = blob_service.generate_container_shared_access_signature(container_name, permission=BlobPermissions.READ, expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1))

   blob_names = blob_service.list_blob_names(container_name, prefix = 'myfolder/')
   blob_urls_with_sas = ['https://'+account_name+'.blob.core.windows.net/'+container_name+'/'+blob_name+'?'+sas_token for blob_name in blob_names]
   ")
   blob_urls_with_sas <- py$blob_urls_with_sas
   ```

   [image]
5. Now, I can use different ways in R to read a csv file from the blob url with sas token, such as below.

   5.1. `df <- read.csv(blob_urls_with_sas[[1]])`

   [image]

   5.2. Using R package `data.table`

   ```
   install.packages("data.table")
   library(data.table)
   df <- fread(blob_urls_with_sas[[1]])
   ```

   [image]

   5.3. Using R package `readr`

   ```
   install.packages("readr")
   library(readr)
   df <- read_csv(blob_urls_with_sas[[1]])
   ```

   [image]

Note: for `reticulate` library, please refer to the RStudio article [`Calling Python from R`](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/calling_python.html).

Hope it helps.

---

Update for your quick question:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time. Let me give this a try and update you further.

Comment: quick question.  What information I need to put in the `account_name = '<your storage account name>'
account_key = '<your storage account key>'
container_name = '<your container name>'   Is it my login ID and password? What is the container name?

Comment: @Crop89 About the `account_name` and `account_key` values, please see my update figure above, and the container name is the blob container you created in your blob storage.

Comment: H @PeterPan, I went through your instructions step by step and unfortunately when I want to run `py_run_string("...code...")` I get the following error:
`Error in py_run_string_impl(code, local, convert): ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'`. Do you know what is causing it and how can I remove it?